# Copy Failed '/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/microservice_app: no such file or directory' Rust Dockerfile

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, rust, dockerfile, rust-cargo

I'm trying run this Docker image, I'm new to Docker world. Help appreciated :)
I'm trying to Run a simple Rust microservice with postgres using Docker on Google Cloud. But After build is finished, it is **not able to copy the binary.**

Cargo.toml :

```
[package]
name = "home_made_rust"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"


[dependencies]
postgres = "0.17.5"
```

below is my Dockerfile

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Cargo Build Stage
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

FROM rust:latest as builder

WORKDIR     /rust

# Download the cargo target
RUN         rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl

# create dummy application, s.t. cargo can download all dependencies
RUN         mkdir -p /rust/app/src && echo 'fn main(){}' > app/src/main.rs
WORKDIR     /rust/app

# Build & cache dependencies
COPY        Cargo.toml Cargo.lock ./
RUN         cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl

# Copy application code
COPY        src ./src

# Build production binary
RUN         touch src/main.rs && cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl

# Production container
FROM        scratch
COPY        --from=builder /rust/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/microservice_app /app
ENTRYPOINT  ["/app"]
```

and this is my Rust project structure

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        30-07-2020  07.36 PM                .github
d-----        30-07-2020  07.24 PM                src
d-----        30-07-2020  07.25 PM                target
-a----        30-07-2020  11.44 PM             19 .dockerignore
-a----        30-07-2020  07.24 PM              8 .gitignore
-a----        30-07-2020  10.58 PM          20573 Cargo.lock
-a----        30-07-2020  10.58 PM            250 Cargo.toml
-a----        31-07-2020  10.31 AM            974 Dockerfile
```

**Exact error from github actions ->**

```
Step 11/12 : COPY        --from=builder /rust/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/microservice_app /app
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/912bcbdb9b9198001ae5d1df4aec09ec54efb413fbb8981d165ee529ea9966a6/merged/rust/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/microservice_app: no such file or directory
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Comment: add `RUN ls -l /rust/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/microservice_app` to your builder dockerfile to check if the folder exist in that image

Comment: Check  microservice_app is getting created properly or not on the same path.

Comment: Thanks guys I think since my package name is: `home_made_rust` binary name might be that. I will update here again about the progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replacing this
`COPY        --from=builder /rust/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/microservice_app /app`

with this =>

```
COPY        --from=builder /rust/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/home_made_rust /app
```

binary name is as per Cargo.toml file

```
[package]
name = "home_made_rust"
```