# How to use a Rust application from a Kotlin application within a docker container?

Tags: java, docker, kotlin, rust, dockerfile

I have a Rust application (written by a different author) which indexes some VCF files. I have written a Kotlin application which takes in some VCF file paths, makes some modifications and fetches data - with which it should then ideally call the aforementioned Rust application.

I have implemented it locally, where I have the Rust application repo built, so I am using DefaultExecutor class to run the Rust application from command line. I want to move the whole process into a docker container. I am confused on how to capture the Rust application within the container. Should I use a `RUN git clone.....` for the Kotlin application Dockerfile to fetch the code (it is a private repo). I wanted to know if there is a better way to implement this instead of pulling the source code inside the container.

Also, not sure if there is a way to get the Rust application executable only inside the docker container. How would this be implemented?

Comment: Rust app can be packaged to native code targeted for the platform of your choice.

Comment: Simply `COPY` the compiled executable to the container.

Comment: Or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63186252/5397009) for an example of a multi-stage Docker configuration that copies the source to an intermediate Docker image for compiling, and then only copies the final executable to the production image.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution you are looking for is called a multi-stage build. Essentially you will want to create a Dockerfile that will have "stages". Each stage will be dedicated to different parts of the build. The final stage will produce the image that is used by containers.

You will probably start with a rust image and then `git clone` your rust app, `cargo install`, and `cargo build` it before moving on to the stage where your Kotlin app is built. Once you get to the stage where you build the Kotlin image you can copy over your built rust executable.

The [official rust image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rust) has an example of this usage

```
FROM rust:1.67 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
COPY . .
RUN cargo install --path .

FROM debian:bullseye-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y extra-runtime-dependencies && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/cargo/bin/myapp /usr/local/bin/myapp
CMD ["myapp"]
```

If you scroll down a bit there is also a link to more information about multi-stage builds. https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/